# Dynamically connect to NodeJS server using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ionic4

I have an ionic chatting app and a nodejs server , it works fine , the only issue that is the server ip/port is hardcoded in a config object.

`let config = { url:"192.168.1.4:3000" , opt: ""}`

But I would like to change this approach, and fetch the server ip/port dynamically or from a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a config.js file and put your things there

Config.js:

```
{
    url:"192.168.1.4:3000"
}
```

And import the file:

```
var cnfg = require('./config');
let config = { url:cnfg.url , opt: ""}
```

Comment: Works in similar situation